# I get more than one master from widget.master (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I just wrote a class in Tkinter, that allows me to make some widgets draggable. This really works great as long as the master of the widget is the root window. But if I, for example, have a Frame with a Lable in it, I can drag the Frame but the Lable just disappears. This is cause the class places the label in relation to the main window. So for example, if the Frame has the size 100x100 and is at the position 500, 500 at the main window, and I drag the Label(0, 0) 1px to the right, it will be placed at 501, 500 instead of 1, 0 cause the class thinks the master is the root window.
So now I thought to just use the master's position to subtract it from the Label position (501-500, 500-500 > 1, 0) There's just one problem. This:

```
f = Frame(root, width=100, height=100, bg='grey')
f.place(x=500, y=500)
l = Label(f, text='Drag me!)
l.place(x=0, y=0)

master = l.master
print(master)
```

returns me not one master but two. Even if there's just one print statement, it gives me this:

```
>>.
>>.!frame
```

If I put a sleep statement in between the declaration and the print it just takes longer. But if I check the types it's not a list, this are two objects.

Can anybody explain this? I just need a way to get the master of the Label to get it's position!

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter widgets exist in a tree structure, and there must be an instance of `Tk` at the root. If you don't create one, it will be created for you the first time you create a widget.

In your output, "." represents the root window that was presumably created for you, and ".!frame" represents the frame.

Though, given the fact that you explicitly pass `root` to `Frame()`, it looks like your code is explicitly creating the root window somewhere.

Comment: I agree with the tree structure, but can you please explain why is `master` attribute of widget returning all the ancestors of the widget? Shouldn't it return just parent which is `frame` for label in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's not a problem with the code. I just didn't noticed I also müde the Frame dragable. And cause the Frames parent is root I got it.